# How can I pre-sign puppet certificates?

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet, cloud

[Puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet/) requires certificates between the client (puppet) being managed and the server (puppetmaster). You can run manually on the client and then go onto the server to sign the certificate, but how do you automate this process for clusters / cloud machines?